# How do I prevent word from copying tabstops?

Tags: microsoft-word-2010, microsoft-word-2007

When I copy text from one word document to another, it also copies tabstops, is there a way to prevent this without resorting to plain text copy? I've set use destination styles when copying between documents and the normal destination style is set to clear all tab stops. However, a tab stop in the original is copied. The original has numbered paragraphs with a tab stop at 0.92 and hanging lines with indentation of 0.92, the target should have both at 1.27 (measures in cm, but that should be irrelevant). The hanging lines do appear at 1.27, but the text in the first line starts at 0.92, the number in the first line does appear at the correct location.

Answer (score 0):

In word your text style has attributes like (color, line-spacing, font-size, tab-stops) and if you copy the text with its style, the whole style is inserted in the new document. What you apparently want is to get certain attributes of the style (all except tabstops) to be copied over from the first document and some chosen attributes (tabstops) to be taken from some style in the second document ?

This would essentialy mean word having to merge styles for you and substitute the "tabstop" attribute in all your copied styles and style-templates with a value from some style in the new document... I don't think its possible.

The easiest would be a plaintext-copy, or just copy it and change the style templates in the new document and change the tabstops there (unless you are not using style templates, then you should copy eveything and while the pasted text is selected just choose edit paragraph and change tabstop settings vor all selected text)